# oriceon/oauth-5-laravel twitter 401 Authorization Required error

Tags: authentication, twitter, oauth, laravel-5, required

I already used facebook api by using this.Then i added

```
'Twitter' => [
    'client_id'     => '**************',
    'client_secret' => '***************',
    // No scope - oauth1 doesn't need scope
],
```

these lines to `config/oauth-5-laravel.php`.
then i add the function

```
public function loginWithTwitter(Request $request)
{
    // get data from request
    $token  = $request->get('oauth_token');
    $verify = $request->get('oauth_verifier');

    // get twitter service
    $tw = \OAuth::consumer('Twitter');

    // check if code is valid

    // if code is provided get user data and sign in
    if ( ! is_null($token) && ! is_null($verify))
    {
        // This was a callback request from twitter, get the token
        $token = $tw->requestAccessToken($token, $verify);

        // Send a request with it
        $result = json_decode($tw->request('account/verify_credentials.json'), true);

        $message = 'Your unique Twitter user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
        echo $message. "<br/>";

        //Var_dump
        //display whole array.
        dd($result);
    }
    // if not ask for permission first
    else
    {
        // get request token
        $reqToken = $tw->requestRequestToken();

        // get Authorization Uri sending the request token
        $url = $tw->getAuthorizationUri(['oauth_token' => $reqToken->getRequestToken()]);

        // return to twitter login url
        return redirect((string)$url);
    }
}
```

to my controller.
but i updated my **composer.json**.
when i connent to twitter..this type of error comes..

```
TokenResponseException in StreamClient.php line 68: Failed to request resource. HTTP Code: HTTP/1.1 401 Authorization Required
```

i think there is a problem at the time of app creation.help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check Your callback url.Twitter doesnt provide testing in localhost.Please check [here](http://iag.me/socialmedia/how-to-create-a-twitter-app-in-8-easy-steps/) for the app creation.